# javascript filtering objects and Arrays

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to learn javascript by following a tutorial on youtube, and I found this segment of code.

I understand what `filter` generally does or at least its purpose, but I don't know anything about `filter` conditions what they do exactly? Any explanation will be appreciated.

```
setFilteredProducts(
    products.filter((item) =>
        Object.entries(filters).every(([key, value]) =>
            item[key].includes(value)
        )
    )
);
```

Comment: You can look for [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), [Object.entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries), [every](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) and [includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)

Comment: best explanation is in MDN

Comment: ^ Agree. Documentation is the best place for this

Comment: _Mozilla Developer Network (MDN)_ will be your friend when it comes to things like this. See the following: [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries), [`Array.prototype.every()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every), and [`Array.prototype.includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes). Also, another good resource: https://javascript.info/

Comment: Yeah theses MDN docs is exactly what i'm looking for , thank you all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
.entries(filters)
```

basically returns an array iterator object which is then being iterated using

```
.every(([key, value])
```

This is basically creating an iterator(entries) and iterating(every) through it.
Finally, `.includes(value)` checks if the `value` is present in `item[key]`. It is basically a function to search for an element.

Hope it helps!